# Make Fluid Invisible for amount of time

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hellow, short question:

How can i make the Fluid domain invisible for specific duration?
I started the fluid simulation on frame X so i need to get rid of the cube for the first X frames. Im using blender 2.8 and noticed i can keyframe the render button, but this doesnt seems to work correctly. Im not into shaders that well so i dont know how exactly i would make the material transparent without killing the current material setup ( its basicly just the principled bsdf and no real "setup")

Would be cool if someone could get me a hand here

Comment: I think animation of visibility is still missing/broken in 2.8 https://developer.blender.org/T58187

Comment: aaw to bad, thx anyway :>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about missing functionality in experimental version of Blender